# Parse String to byte array C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have done the following to convert the byte array to string to store in the db

```
byte[] value;
String stValue = BitConverter.ToString(value);
```

Now I just want do do the opposite

```
String stValue;
byte[] value= (Convert) stValue ???
```

How to do this??

Comment: you didn't perform a single google Search on this did you?

Comment: I have and i am getting different value when doing Encoding.Default.GetBytes(stValue);

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using the `BitConverter`, the string you get is specifically formatted in a less than friendly way. To reverse this process, you can write a custom method to deserialize the bytes like this:

```
public static byte[] GetBytes(string value)
{
    return value.Split('-').Select(s => byte.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();
}
```

Or as *Ben Voigt* [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872911/parse-string-to-byte-array-c-sharp/15872939?noredirect=1#comment37391293_15872939):

```
public static byte[] GetBytes(string value)
{
    return Array.ConvertAll(value.Split('-'), s => byte.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
}
...

var originalBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var stValue = BitConverter.ToString(originalBytes); // "01-02-03-04-05"
var bytes = GetBytes(stValue); // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

However, usually don't *need* to use the `BitConverter`. [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is a more compact and efficient way of encoding random bytes, and you won't have to create a custom decoder:

```
var originalBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var stValue = Convert.ToBase64String(originalBytes); // "AQIDBAU="
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(stValue); // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

On the other hand, the `Encoding` class offers similar functionality for converting between strings and bytes. *Although a given encoding may not be able to translate a random sequence of bytes into a string* so it's best to use this method only if you know the string is valid first:

```
var originalValue = "Hello World";
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalValue); // [ 72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100 ]
var stValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes); // "Hello World"
```

Comment: It gives me different value

Comment: I am getting the following error. (Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'double') while using byte[] value = BitConverter.GetBytes(stValue);

Comment: @LynAs I apologize, I could've sworn there was an override for `BitConverter.GetBytes(string)`, I've updated my answer with a few different alternatives.

Comment: For the first case, `Array.ConvertAll` is a little nicer than LINQ (no need for an extra `ToArray()`)

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point. I've updated for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx) method;

```
byte[] value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stValue);
```

> Encodes all the characters in the specified string into a sequence of
> bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
byte[] value = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(stValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which conversion you desire, there are different ways to achieve this. There is `System.Text.Encoding` and in there `UTF8`, `Unicode`, and `ASCII`. So as you desire

```
byte[] strArray = System.Text.Encoding.(UTF8 | ASCII | Unicode).GetBytes(str);
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes.aspx) for a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const string input = "Dot Net Perls";

    // Invoke GetBytes method.
    // ... You can store this array as a field!
    byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

    // Loop through contents of the array.
    foreach (byte element in array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", element, (char)element);
    }
```

**OutPut**

68 = D,
111 = o,
116 = t,
32 =,
78 = N,
101 = e,
116 = t,
32 =,
80 = P,
101 = e,
114 = r,
108 = l,
115 = s,

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] arr=str.Split('-');
byte[] array=new byte[arr.Length];
for(int i=0; i<arr.Length; i++) array[i]=Convert.ToByte(arr[i],16);
```

This is what i needed. Thanks @Shekhar